# How to Bind array from spark to javascript in zeppelin?

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, apache-zeppelin

Hello I m working with zeppelin to visualize some Dashboards, I m using Angularjs interpreter to display system to configure spark queries, So I want to add autocomplete to the input text box in angularJs, the list that will be used to autocomplete will be created first in spark Then I want to Bind it into zeppelinContext Then get this  list from angular to be javascript script to create the autocomplete

Here an example:

**Paragraph 1:**

```
     %spark.pyspark
      cList5 =  df_ClientDataF1.select(col("type")).filter(col("type").isNotNull()).distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()
      z.z.angularBind("cList5",cList5)
```

**Paragraph 2:**

```
   %angular
   <form autocomplete="off">
   <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
   <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
   </div>
   <input type="submit">
   </form>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var element = $('#someId');
   var angularVar = 'cList5';
   var scope = angular.element(element.parent('.ng- scope')).scope().compiledScope;

     function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
    /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
   the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
    var currentFocus;
 /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
      .
      .
      .
   /*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
     autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), scope);
  </script>
```

Resulting variable scope is an object and I tried to convert it to an array and it failed. the problem is how to get the bound list from spark in javascript as an array type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to the exact opposite thing :D but [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xU5TBS_MsAs) is fine YT video. Might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to make a `html element` and hide the output of the element.
You can then access this element inner html from the script.
I know this is a hack, but I have not figured out a better way

```
%angular

<p id="demo" class="hide">{{cList5}}</p>

<script>
    var angularVar = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML
    console.log(angularVar)
</script>
```

You might have to do additional modificationn. But for example passing Json as string and the parsing it in the scipt works just fine.